# Can I get Powershell object's noteproperty by number/id instead of its name?

Tags: powershell

```
$s = import-csv AAPL.csv
$s | gm
TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
Adj Close   NoteProperty System.String Adj Close=103.739998
Close       NoteProperty System.String Close=103.739998
Date        NoteProperty System.String Date=2015-08-03
High        NoteProperty System.String High=122.57
Low         NoteProperty System.String Low=92.00
Open        NoteProperty System.String Open=121.50
Volume      NoteProperty System.String Volume=82932100

# $ts = $s.'Adj Close'         //OK
# $ts = $s[ 0 .. $s.Count][3]  //Anyway of doing this? suppose 'Adj Close' is on column 4.
```

I am wondering if I can get NoteProperty value by a positional number/id.

I am thinking this because  I may encounter financial data that do not have the exact name as 'Adj Close' , such as 'Last Close', 'Close', 'Adjusted Close' etc... on the same column and that can be analyzed using the same code.

Thank you!

Comment: Would `$s | select -property *Close*` work for this, or is it more diverse?

Comment: Not exactly, It will contain 'Adj Close' and Close columns. But you inspired me for an answer anyway! Just `$s | select -property 'Adj Close', 'Price', 'etc...'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to select CSV columns with fuzzy names, you can [use a regex to select the column names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8525481/503046).

As for a working sample, let's pick some columns:

```
# Test data
$data = @'
"Last Close", "Close", "Adjusted Close", "Other Close"
10, 20, 30, 40
50, 60, 70, 80
'@

# Convert here-string into csv so it behaves like import-csv's output
$csvdata = convertfrom-csv $data

# Match only Close header by looking at headers and picking just it
[string[]]$headers = $csvdata | gm -MemberType "noteproperty" | 
                        ?{ $_.Name -match "^Close$"} | 
                        select -expand Name
$csvdata | select $headers
Close
-----
20
60

# Match Last or Adjusted Close with same technique
[string[]]$headers = $csvdata | gm -MemberType "noteproperty" | 
                        ?{ $_.Name -match "^((Last)|(Adjusted)) Close$"} | 
                        select -expand Name
$csvdata | select $headers
Adjusted Close Last Close
-------------- ----------
30             10
70             50
```